# How do I start building a C# customization in SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, column, custom

I've never built a sharepoint customization...ever. But I'm quite handy with c# and I need some kind of pointer on where to start.

I want to create a custom list column which will be

1. encrypted
2. password protected
3. make it possible to decide which roles should have access to it:

   - Everyone
   - Users member of a certain role
   - Creator of list row

The column should be visible for everyone but the content needs to be masked if the logged in user does not fulfill the criterias above.

Now I don't need you guys to solve the issues above but only point me to where I can begin experimenting with creating a custom list column.

Comment: Don't want to be sarcastic, but good luck with creating something that "complex" in SharePoint Online. Development with SPO is very limited compared to what we could do with SharePoint on-prem (where server-side C# code is allowed... while in SPO you only have access to remote API!).

Comment: Really? I thought you had server side c# code in SP online as well...?

Comment: ya, not going to be possible, anything you can do is just obscuring the underlying data they would have access to. The *only* way this is workable is if it is a provider hosted app and SharePoint Online just reads the data.

Comment: Alright, so lets say I do it with client-side scripting would that be possible?

Comment: No, because it would only obscure what they already have access to, they could get to the data if they tried. There is no elevation of privileges on the client side either.

Comment: @EricAlexander Ok thanks, then I guess this is a no-go...

Comment: Ok so now I've changed scope of question, just tell me where I can learn how to build a custom list column? I've given up the idea of what I described before BUT I still want to know how to make customization in SP Online.

Comment: You can get some reference from this link: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-or-add-a-column-in-a-list-or-library-2b0361ae-1bd3-41a3-8329-269e5f81cfa2

Comment: @DikeshGandhi No not really, that only covers standard sharepoint and sharepoint developer...or am I missing something here? I want to build code in Visual Studio and make it run in Sharepoint Online...

Comment: Restart... Forget technology and do what Steve Jobs left us with.. "Work from the Customer back to Technology".. NOT the other way around. ►What do you want to do with that Custom List Column? What is the user going to do with it, what is going to be stored, and what other systems might be involved... In my mothers words "If you want tomato soup you need to buy tomatoes"

Comment: Link from Dikesh Gandhi is indeed about SP on-prem. Creating a custom column with such advanced capacities is way out off the capabilities of SP Online. So, either go back on-prem, or, as Danny suggests, re-think the initial needs. :( Hooray for the cloud (I'm being sarcastic this time).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi everybody and thank you for your contribution.

I've found a solution for this using client-side scripting to encrypt the column value before save, thus the information is encrypted in the database and you'll need a password together with a encryption key to decrypt the column value and show it in a readable format.

To achieve this I've looked at this project and adjusted a lot of the code.
https://spcrypto.codeplex.com/

It works satisfactory for my needs in SharePoint online.